# Scala future execution

Tags: multithreading, scala, future, executioncontext

I have two futures. I want to execute them in order. For example:

```
val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val first=Future.successful(...)
val second=Future.successful(...)
```

When first is completed then second should be executed. The problem is that second should return `Future[Object]`  not `Future[Unit]` so 
I can not use completed, `andThen` etc. functions
I can not block the process using `await` or `Thread.sleep(...)`
I can not use for loop since execution context is defined like this.

`first.flatmap( _=> second)` will not execute in order.
How can I do that?

Comment: just make `second` a `def` instead of a `val`?

Comment: Maybe you can use some polling of first `Future` for completion, and when it is completed run the second one.

Comment: following @SaschaKolberg's suggestion, try defining both `first` and `second` as `def` rather than `val`, then `first.flatmap( _=> second)` will complete the two futures sequentially and in order. (there's no great need to define `first` as a `def`, but for symmetry it seems nice. if first is `def`, and reference to first will re-excute `Future.successful(...)`.)

Comment: It did not work since when second takes the first value, it returns. It will not wait until first finishes.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you assign a `Future` to a val, that `Future` is scheduled and will execute as soon as possible. To prevent this you have two options:

1. Define the `Future` in a `def`
2. Define the `Future` where you want to use it.

Here's an example of #1:

```
def first: Future[Int] = Future { Thread.sleep(5000); 1 }
def second(i: Int): Future[Unit] = Future { println(i) }
first.flatMap(i => second(i))
```

And here's an example of #2:

```
for(
  i <- Future { Thread.sleep(5000); 1 };
  _ <- Future { println(i) }
) yield ()
```

Both examples will wait for 5 seconds and print then 1